# How to create Excel file and fill data into it with C# and asp.net on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi guys i am trying to create an excel, fill it and download it. I was trying lots of different things, but I read recently, that Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is not beeing supported by Windows Server 2012, how should I do it differently?

Here is the Code i was trying. It works fine on the local Version, but seems not to work on the Server. I hope there is some advice or maybe some code i could be using.

Thanks a lot

```
 using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Kalkulation");
        //On the Server is a differen Path
        FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(@"Path");
        excel.SaveAs(excelFile);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet = null;

        try
        {
            oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            //On the Server is a differen Path
            oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(@"Path");
            oSheet = String.IsNullOrEmpty("Kalkulation") ? (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet : (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets["Kalkulation"];

            oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Kalkulation: " + lbl_title.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Produktname";
            oSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "Dimension";
            oSheet.Cells[3, 4] = "Preis";
            oSheet.Cells[3, 5] = "Zeit";
            oSheet.Cells[3, 6] = "Anzahl";
            oSheet.Cells[3, 7] = "Totalzeit";
            oSheet.Cells[3, 8] = "Totalpreis";

            oSheet.get_Range("C1", "H100").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

            oSheet.get_Range("B1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;
            oSheet.get_Range("B1", "B1").Font.Size = 20;
            oSheet.get_Range("B1", "B1").RowHeight = 59;

            oSheet.get_Range("D1", "D1").Font.Bold = true;
            oSheet.get_Range("D1", "D1").Font.Size = 20;
            oSheet.get_Range("D1", "D1").RowHeight = 59;

            oSheet.get_Range("B3", "H3").Font.Bold = true;
            oSheet.get_Range("B3", "H3").Font.Size = 12;
            oSheet.get_Range("B3", "H3").RowHeight = 32;

            oSheet.Rows.RowHeight = 25;
            oSheet.Rows.ColumnWidth = 25;

            int s = 4;
            foreach (RepeaterItem rptItem in rpt.Items)
            {
                s++;
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblName = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)rptItem.FindControl("lblName");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl_Dimension_O = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)rptItem.FindControl("lbl_Dimension_O");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl_Dimension_U = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)rptItem.FindControl("lbl_Dimension_U");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl_price = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)rptItem.FindControl("lbl_price");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl_time = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)rptItem.FindControl("lbl_time");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl_quantity = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)rptItem.FindControl("lbl_quantity");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl_fulltime = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)rptItem.FindControl("lbl_fulltime");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl_fullprice = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)rptItem.FindControl("lbl_fullprice");
                oSheet.Cells[s, 2] = lblName.Text;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lbl_Dimension_O.Text) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lbl_Dimension_U.Text))
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[s, 3] = lbl_Dimension_O.Text + " / " + lbl_Dimension_U.Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[s, 3] = "";
                }

                oSheet.Cells[s, 4] = lbl_price.Text;
                oSheet.Cells[s, 5] = lbl_time.Text;
                oSheet.Cells[s, 6] = lbl_quantity.Text;
                oSheet.Cells[s, 7] = lbl_fulltime.Text;
                oSheet.Cells[s, 8] = lbl_fullprice.Text;

            }

            s = s + 2;
            oSheet.Cells[s, 6] = "Provisorisch Total: ";
            oSheet.get_Range("F" + s, "F" + s + 3).Font.Bold = true;
            oSheet.Cells[s, 7] = lblTotalTime.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[s, 8] = lblTotal.Text;
            s++;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblTotalwRabatt_2.Text) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblTotalwRabatt.Text))
            {
                oSheet.Cells[s, 6] = "Korrekur:";
                oSheet.get_Range("F" + s, "F" + s).Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblTotalwRabatt_2.Text))
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[s, 7] = Minus_2.Text + " " + lblDifferenz_2.Text;
                    oSheet.get_Range("G" + s, "G" + s).Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;


                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblTotalwRabatt.Text))
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[s, 8] = lblMinus.Text + " " + lblDifferenz.Text;
                    oSheet.get_Range("H" + s, "H" + s).Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                }
                s++;
                oSheet.Cells[s, 6] = "Total:";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblTotalwRabatt_2.Text))
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[s, 7] = lblTotalwRabatt_2.Text;
                    oSheet.get_Range("G" + s, "G" + s).Font.Bold = true;
                    oSheet.get_Range("G" + s, "G" + s).Font.Size = 12;

                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblTotalwRabatt.Text))
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[s, 8] = lblTotalwRabatt.Text;
                    oSheet.get_Range("H" + s, "H" + s).Font.Bold = true;
                    oSheet.get_Range("H" + s, "H" + s).Font.Size = 12;
                }
            }



            oWB.Save();

            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Details.xlsx");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (oWB != null)
                oWB.Close();
        }


        //On the Server is a differen Path
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Path");
```

Comment: Is there any exceptions?

Comment: No there aren't, local it downloads and opens the excel file and as soon as i start the website with IIS and access it through internet, it downloads me the .aspx file. With debug it gives no exceptions

Comment: ok, and what is in .aspx file?

Comment: and why do you invoke this `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Path");`?

Comment: oh my, I think I got it. Is `ExcelPackage` is come from `EPPlus` nuget package?

Comment: In the aspx file, there is the Code that i have written. System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Path"); With that I just open the File, so it is visible as soon as you click it.

Comment: Yea i think so, should be, i saw other people using EPPlus nuget and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel @.@

Comment: Well then, first of all ensure, that there is a proper version of MS Office is installed on your server. Then, keep in mind, that `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Path");` will try to open Excel on server, not on client. And lastly, add some code to log your exception in `catch (Exception ex)` (or debug it remotly on server, if you can)

Comment: MS Office is installed, i am creating the excel file and i would like to open the file on the clients pc, because if it makes just a download, the user can't open the file. I got no Idea why not. It says that Excel cannot open the File because the file format or file extension is not valid.

Comment: and one more: if .aspx file with your code is downloaded, instead of being invoked, there is should be an error in your IIS configuration

Comment: Alright i will take a look at the logs

Comment: i found this:Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.8431.2250, time stamp: 0x5ae39f49
Faulting module name: VCRUNTIME140.dll, version: 14.10.25017.0, time stamp: 0x58a63e49
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000d3d0
Faulting process id: 0x9330
Faulting application start time: 0x01d40c62cb8c2d3f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
Report Id: 0993932b-7856-11e8-80fc-0050568f6aa2
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: I think this is because you trying to start excel from service process (where there is no desktop and application windows at all), so Excel is dying. Try to remove `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Path");`

Comment: Makes no difference, it still downloads the aspx file instead of the excel file. In the IIS logs is nothing of error about this. I don't event know what the problem could be my mind is blowing up))

Comment: One more thing to test, what is HTTP status-code with returning .aspx file?

Comment: It creates the file but with no content, but the content is beeing taken from the database. Everything works fine and also the query, db connection exists. But no data is beeing filled and no download off excel file is available

Comment: first status is 302 for login and then 200